# JavaScript tic tak toe program not working

Tags: javascript

```
    <html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"
    <title> "tic tac toe"</title>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        var Next = "X";
        var count = "O";
        var square= new Array()
        for (var i=0; i<9; i++) square[i] = true;
        function makeMove(squareindex)                  
        {
            if (square [squareindex] == true;
            }
            (square [squareindex] == true;
                count++;
                document.getElementById(squareindex).value = ""+next+"";
                if Next == "X";
                {
                    Next == "O";
                }
                else
                {
                    Next == "X";
                }
                if (count == 9) document.getElementById("toeDisplay").innerHTML="Game Over!";
                else document.getElementById("toeDisplay").innerHTML= It is/""+next+""/'s turn";
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById("toeDisplay").innerHTML = "Fail";
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;tic tac toe
    <table border=1 id="tictactable"><form name="tic tac toe"></form>   
        <tr>
            <td id="toeDisplay" colspan=4 align=center bgcolor=white> It is "X"'s turn</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>                                                         
            <td align=center><INPUT id="0" TYPE="button" value="  "onClick="makeMove(0)"></td>          
            <td align=center><INPUT id="1" TYPE="button" value="  "onClick="makeMove(1)"></td>  
            <td align=center><INPUT id="2" TYPE="button" value="  "onClick="makeMove(2)"></td>
        </tr>                                                  
        <tr>                                                
            <td align=center><INPUT id="3" TYPE="button" value="  "onClick="makeMove(3)"></td>      
            <td align=center><INPUT id="4" TYPE="button" value="  "onClick="makeMove(4)"></td> 
            <td align=center><INPUT id="5" TYPE="button" value="  "onClick="makeMove(5)"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align=center><INPUT id="6" TYPE="button" value="  "onClick="makeMove(6)"></td>
            <td align=center><INPUT id="7" TYPE="button" value="  "onClick="makeMove(7)"></td>
            <td align=center><INPUT id="8" TYPE="button" value="  "onClick="makeMove(8)"></td>
        </tr> 
</table>        

</body>
</html>
```

Hi there! I got this code for a JavaScript tic-tac-toe program and cant get it to work. What am i doing wrong? I made spell checks and didn't find any thing and still it wont work. Its supposed to function like a normal game of tic-tac-toe. Your "X" and the computer would be "O". It would make the computer make a move when you hit a button, and i cant seem to get that to work.

Comment: Numerous typos and errors in this. Unclosed parentheses, brackets going wrong way. Work through the errors in chrome developer tools console.

Comment: Have a look at your html also, it's not entirely valid.

Answer (score 1):

This is invalid code... `if (square [squareindex] == true;` is not proper JavaScript syntax. You would have to do `if (square [squareindex] == true) {`.

If you open the Chrome Developer Tools, you'd see errors in the Console:

[image]

The code is sprinkled with these kinds of issues. Fix them and then try again. You can refer to Douglas Crockford's JavaScript: The Good Parts as a good reference for syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Well, just look at the colour-coding, for one. You're missing quotes in places, especially your "it is ...'s turn".

Aside from that, your number one problem is the very first `if`, you have a semicolon instead of a closing parenthesis.

You should use a code editor such as Notepad++ that includes syntax highlighting and bracket matching, it makes finding errors like this much easier ;)

EDIT: I've made an example implementation of Tic-Tac-Toe. [Link](http://jsbin.com/evasoj/1/edit). Take a look at the code used to make it.